# How do I implement a Schwartzian Transform in Python?

Tags: python, sorting

In Perl I sometimes use the [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) to efficiently sort complex arrays:

```perl
@sorted = map  { $_->[0] }  # sort by word length
          sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } # use numeric comparison
          map  { [$_, length($_)] }    # calculate the length of the string
               @unsorted;
```

How to implement this transform in Python?

Comment: You don't need it in Python, just supply an appropriate `key` function to sorting functions

Comment: Read this: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/i-want-to-do-a-complicated-sort-can-you-do-a-schwartzian-transform-in-python.htm

Comment: You probably don't need it in Perl either. Most times I have seen a transform used it was to make the author feel clever. Always profile your code before optimising it.

Comment: Perl: Or use the Sort::Key family of modules to get a simple interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to.  Python has this feature built in, and in fact Python 3 *removed* C-style custom comparisons because this is so much better in the vast majority of cases.

To sort by word length:

```
unsorted.sort(key=lambda item: len(item))
```

Or, because `len` is already an unary function:

```
unsorted.sort(key=len)
```

This also works with the built-in `sorted` function.

If you want to sort on multiple criteria, you can take advantage of the fact that tuples sort lexicographically:

```
# sort by word length, then alphabetically in case of a tie
unsorted.sort(key=lambda item: (len(item), item)))
```

Comment: I see in the docs the the function is called once per element. Does that mean that python uses additional data structure to map the keys to the results of the  function?

Comment: @planetp it would have to, yes, though the exact details are irrelevant to python-land  :)  i believe it's just a temporary parallel c array

Comment: @ikegami "The key corresponding to each item in the list is calculated once and then used for the entire sorting process."

Comment: If you need to sort by multiple criteria with some of them reversed (descending vs. ascending), [this is how](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts).

Answer (score 0):

While there should normally be no reason not to use the `key` argument for the `sorted` function or `list.sort` method, you can of course do without it, by creating a list of pairs (called `tmp` below) where the first item is the sort key and the second item is the original item.

Due to lexicographical sorting, sorting this list will sort by the key first. Then you can take the items in the desired order from the sorted `tmp` list of pairs.

```
example = ["hello", "spam", "foo"]

tmp = []
for item in example:
    sort_key = len(item)
    tmp.append((sort_key, item))

# tmp: [(5, "hello"), (4, "spam"), (3, "foo")]

tmp.sort()

# tmp: [(3, "foo"), (4, "spam"), (5, "hello")]

result = []
for _, item in tmp:
    result.append(item)

# result: ["foo", "spam", "hello"]
```

Note that usually this would be written with list comprehensions instead of calling `.append` in a loop, but the purpose of this answer is to illustrate the underlying algorithm in a way most likely to be understood by beginners.